# Inverse Jacobian Matrix without moveit

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I want to know please how can I get the **jacobian matrix** and its **inversion** via ROS tools.
I have calculated a jacobian matrix and applied the inversion using c++ code and I am getting wrong results.
Can you please guide me solving this?
I have to get at least a good way to make the inversion of my 6 by 6 jacobian matrix.
For the moment, I am using the following code to get the inversion:
[https://github.com/bluelul/InverseMatrix/blob/master/INVERSE_MATRIX.cpp]
Thank you by advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368987/inverse-jacobian-matrix-without-moveit/) by [baklouti-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/62010/baklouti-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2021-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

Several days ago I tried the Orocos-KDL  forward and inverse kinematics solvers including inverse velocity (cartesian space to joint space) solver/algorithm. Is your task a robot velocity control? If yes, I will extract and post example of code...

Best wishes,
Maxim.

---

Originally posted by [MaximN74](https://answers.ros.org/users/37023/maximn74/) with karma: 73 on 2021-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Blaubär](https://answers.ros.org/users/68112/blaub%C3%A4r/) on 2021-01-21**:
Hi Maxim,
I'm currently also working on velocity control using Orocos-KDL and would highly appreciate that example code you were talking about!